# SharePoint Configuration

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I have installed SharePoint in app server and web server, it is a 3-tier farm.How to configure IIS APP Pool account for a web application in SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 3):

Changing App Pool required couple of steps, if you miss any of it, web application stop working.

1. Make Sure the New app Pool account must have permission to Config DB, Central Admin Db, State Service, Profile Dbs and all content DB attached to the web app.
2. Make sure new app pool account should be member of IIS_Iusr and wss-wpg-admin groups on server
3. 1st add the new account into the Managed Account( if it is not already in). Central Admin > Security > Managed accounts. register here.
4. Now from Central Admin > Security > manage service accounts and change the account here.
5. now reset IIS on all servers.
6. test

Answer (score 1):

In Central Administration -> Security -> Configure Service Accounts. You can change the account used for the web app.